# Do you know any direct way in Excel VBA to select multiple worksheets already in an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, select, worksheet

I have a piece of code that creates a variable number of copies from a worksheet.
Every new copy is set as the next Worksheet type variable in an array:

```
Dim wsv() as Worksheet
Dim ddf as Integer, i as Integer

'After some processing, ddf will define the number of copies required,
'therefore the size of the array.

'ws is the original worksheet from which the copies will be made

If ddf > 0 then

    ReDim wsv(0 to ddf) as Worksheet
    
    For i = 0 to ddf
        ws.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Set wsv(i) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Next i

End if
```

I need to select all these new worksheets in the end, in order to export them as a single PDF.

I have used `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select` in situations where the quantity/name of the worksheets to select is known, and I was hoping that `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsv).Select` or `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(wsv)).Select` would work in this particular one, but they don't.

Do you know how can I do this, taking advantage of having all required sheets to select already in an array?

**UPDATE:**

I needed to use an array of strings instead, since that's what `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select` expects.
Thanks to @BigBen and @VBasic2008 for your help!

Comment: Make an array of their names.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same situation? How do you suggest I could transpose the sheet names to the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(...))` ?

Comment: You're already creating an array - just change it to be an array of `String`s and populate it with their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Worksheets Array

- The function `createWorksheetsArray` is kind of a hybrid. It creates new worksheets like a `Sub` would do, and it returns the array of worksheet names of the newly created worksheets, like a `Function` would do.
- The procedure `testCreateWorksheetsArray` adds three worksheets to the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`), returns the three names in an array whose contents are printed to the `Immediate window` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> before all three worksheets are deleted 'in one go'.
- Instead of deleting, you will rather do something like this:

  ```
  wb.Worksheets(wsv).Select
  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat...
  ```

**New Version**

```
Option Explicit

Sub addWorksheetCopies(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                       Optional ByVal NumberOfCopies As Long = 1)
    
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    If NumberOfCopies < 1 Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    With Sheet
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 1 To NumberOfCopies
            .Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count)
        Next n
    End With

ProcExit:

End Sub

Function getLastWorkSheetNames(Book As Workbook, _
                               Optional ByVal NumberOfWorksheets As Long) _
         As Variant
    
    Dim wsCounter As Long
    wsCounter = NumberOfWorksheets
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To wsCounter)
    Dim shCounter As Long
    shCounter = Book.Sheets.Count
    
    Dim sh As Object
    Do
        Set sh = Book.Sheets(shCounter)
        If sh.Type = xlWorksheet Then
            Data(wsCounter) = sh.Name
            wsCounter = wsCounter - 1
            shCounter = shCounter - 1
        End If
    Loop Until wsCounter = 0
    getLastWorkSheetNames = Data

ProcExit:

End Function

Sub testBoth()
    
    Const NumberOfCopies As Long = 3
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Create copies of Source Worksheet.
    addWorksheetCopies ws, NumberOfCopies
    
    ' Write the names of the copies to Worksheets Array ('wsv').
    Dim wsv As Variant
    wsv = getLastWorkSheetNames(wb, NumberOfCopies)
    If IsEmpty(wsv) Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Status:
    ' You have created your copies of worksheet ws,
    ' and the array wsv contains the names of the copied worksheets.
    ' Continue...
    
    ' e.g.
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(wsv) To UBound(wsv)
        Debug.Print wsv(n)
    Next n
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Worksheets(wsv).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
ProcExit:
    
End Sub
```

**Code Smell Version (not recommended)**

```
Function createWorksheetsArray(SourceWorksheet As Worksheet, _
                               Optional ByVal NumberOfCopies As Long = 1) _
         As Variant
    
    If SourceWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    If NumberOfCopies < 1 Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To NumberOfCopies)
    With SourceWorksheet
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 1 To NumberOfCopies
            .Copy After:=.Parent.Sheets(.Parent.Sheets.Count)
            Data(n) = .Parent.ActiveSheet.Name
        Next n
    End With

    createWorksheetsArray = Data

ProcExit:

End Function

Sub testCreateWorksheetsArray()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim wsv As Variant
    wsv = createWorksheetsArray(ws, 3)
    If IsEmpty(wsv) Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = LBound(wsv) To UBound(wsv)
        Debug.Print wsv(n)
    Next n
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Worksheets(wsv).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
ProcExit:
    
End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest, your function doing two things is a code smell.

Comment: @BigBen: I will have to agree. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I think the adding of copies is not relevant to OP, I would delete it. If the function is called, `createWorksheetsArray`, then it should do just that.

Comment: @BigBen: I would say it might be an XY problem, because I assume that OP wants to create those worksheets, then using the array of names do some modifications on them and then again, using the array, export those worksheets to PDF. Maybe creating those worksheets and then looping through the last worksheets in the workbook might be a better way.

Comment: Another option `Dim wsNames() As String`, `ReDim wsNames(0 to ddf) as String`, `wsNames(i) = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name`. Make that into its own separate function and voila..

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thanks for your detailed answer! You helped me confirming that the solution was as simple as only using the sheet names instead, as previously mentioned by BigBen Thank you both!

Comment: @BigBen: I would appreciate it if you would comment on the new version.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - looks like OP has the answer, so refactoring is good but probably unnecessary to the thread.

Answer (score 2):

**Late addition to "How to select multiple worksheets?"**

As Jorge mentioned in the updated question

> *"I needed to use an* **array of strings** *instead"*

let me continue the chain of thought:

1. On the one hand using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select` or
   or a predefined array via `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsNames).Select`
   actually has to correspond to an array containing **strings**.

   Btw, instead of selecting the *entire sheets list*,
   it's also possible to enlarge a selection group *one by one*:

```
    Sub SelectWorksheets()
    Dim wsNames As Variant  ' Split needs a variant array type
    wsNames = Split("Tabelle1,Tabelle2", ","): If UBound(wsNames) = -1 Then Exit Sub
    'a) select first sheet thus removing any prior selection
        Dim i As Long: i = LBound(wsNames)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsNames(i)).Select
    'b) select next items
        For i = i + 1 To UBound(wsNames)
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsNames(i))
                'add to existing selection
                .Select (False) ' note the False argument adding to existing selection

                'do further stuff
                '...
            End With
        Next i
    End Sub
```

2. On the other hand Jorge firstly tried to declare the `Worksheet` type, why not?

   Therefore I demonstrate an alternative using immediately the project's sheet ►**Code(Names)**:

```
    Sub SelectViaCodeNames()
    Dim wsCodes: wsCodes = Array(Tabelle1, Tabelle2): If UBound(wsCodes) = -1 Then Exit Sub
    'a) select first sheet thus removing any prior selection
        Dim i As Long: i = LBound(wsCodes)
        wsCodes(i).Select
    'b) select next items
        For i = i + 1 To UBound(wsCodes)
            With wsCodes(i)
                'add to existing  selection
                .Select (False)
            
                'do further stuff
                '...
            End With
        Next i
    End Sub
```

*The only draw back is, that afaik you can't pass the entire Code(Name) list as argument to a comparable object like the `Worksheets` collection.*

Comment: Thanks. Quite interesting. Never seen `.Select (False)`.